# SendJsonAsync makes function return without executing following code

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I'm digging my way into Blazor, using [this tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-an-application-using-blazor-and-entity-framework-core-1c1679d87c7e) to create a simple demo program with a database connection.

These are the three main functions to call the controller:

```
protected async Task CreateEmployee() {
    await http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/Employee/Create", emp);
    UriHelper.NavigateTo("/");
}

protected async Task UpdateEmployee() {
    await http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Put, "api/Employee/Edit", emp);
    UriHelper.NavigateTo("/");
}

protected async Task Delete() {
    await http.DeleteAsync("api/Employee/Delete/" + Convert.ToInt32(id));
    UriHelper.NavigateTo("/");
}
```

The main functionality of creating/editing/deleting entities works fine, however the redirection afterwards only works for the latest function.

Via debugging I found out the SendJsonAsync method makes the function return without executing the following code, though in the example it seems to be working fine.

Is there an obvious solution that I'm missing?

Comment: The function _will_ return after the call to `await` (that's how the async state machine works) but it will then _resume_ after the call to await, so `UriHelper.NavigateTo` should eventually get called.  Did you look at the network tab in your browser to see if the server returned a status code indicating it wasn't successful?